# How to apply a rule in laravel to check filename is unique?

Tags: laravel

In laravel 8 how can use the validation to check the file name provided in the array were unique.

```
` "main": [
        {
            "content": "ABC",
            "filename": "recording_1",
            "code": "264",
            "parameters": ""
        },
        {
            "content": "XYZ",
            "filename": "recording_2",
            "code": "264",
            "parameters": ""
        } 

        ...more to come
]`
```

Above is the request structure. From that request, I have to check the all filename should be unique
How can I achieve this?

Comment: As in unique in the request or unique in the database?

Comment: Unique in request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use  `distinct`

```
$validator = Validator::make(
        [
            'main' =>
                [
                    [
                        "content" => "ABC",
                        "filename" => "recording_1",
                        "code" => "264",
                        "parameters" => ""
                    ],
                    [
                        "content" => "XYZ",
                        "filename" => "recording_1",
                        "code" => "264",
                        "parameters" => ""
                    ]


                ]
        ],
        ['main.*.filename' => 'distinct']
    );
```

then you can check

```
if($validator->fails()){
        echo  "<pre>";
        print_r($validator->errors());
        exit();
    }
```

Output will be

```
Illuminate\Support\MessageBag Object
(
    [messages:protected] => Array
        (
            [main.0.filename] => Array
                (
                    [0] => The main.0.filename field has a duplicate value.
                )

            [main.1.filename] => Array
                (
                    [0] => The main.1.filename field has a duplicate value.
                )

        )

    [format:protected] => :message
)
```

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-distinct

Comment: Just an FYI, you can use [dump()/dd()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-dd) instead of the `<pre>` and `print_r()` stuff.

Comment: yes i know but for formatting in stakcoverflow bit diffcult if i use dd or dump.for that i used print_r